# Solving a matrix equation for arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I am trying to find the following matrix, $B$ using the following matrix equation,

\begin{equation}
A = B^{T}CB
\end{equation}

where we have the matrices A and C. I know that $B^{T}=B$, but trying to use a $2$ x $2$ matrix for each of the matrices, respectively, representing $B$ symbolically only I am left with $2$, $2$ x $2$ matrices on each side of the equality. Is there any literature for a general way for solving this matrix equation? Thank you

Comment: two square matrices $A$ and $C$ are called [congruent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) if there exists an invertible matrix $B$ such that $A=B^T C B$

Comment: In general, there is no reason to have $B^T = B$ here.

Comment: @lastgunslinger, every script or linear algebra book.